# How to retrieve sane stdout/stderr logging for Elastic Beanstalk deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, codeship

When I attempt an elastic beanstalk deployment, one of my `container_commands` may fail. Unfortunately, the elastic beanstalk log `eb-commandprocessor.log` only reports a non-zero exit status:

`Error occurred during build: Command 08_collectstatic failed (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)`

The rest of the `stdout`/`stderr` apparently fails to log because of Unicode characters. (I've successfully troubleshooted other failed commands because of Unicode quote marks, etc). I have attached the log below.

---

As an example, doing something like `ln -s Gruntfile.js Gruntfile.js` would raise an error with `ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘Gruntfile.js’: File exists`. The left- and right- angled quote marks are Unicode and upset Elastic Beanstalk logging -- apparently.

**I really need sane output from stdout/stderr to troubleshoot the underlying issue in the container command failure and I don't know how I can patch EB to log this.** How can I achieve this?

---

*.ebextensions/05_container_commands.config*

```html
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles
    option_name: /static/
    value: static/
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python
    option_name: WSGIPath
    value: wsgi.py
  - option_name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
    value: settings

container_commands:
  08_collectstatic:
    command: "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
```

---

*/var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log*

```html
-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log
-------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 799, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)
Error occurred during build: Command 08_collectstatic failed (ElasticBeanstalk::ActivityFatalError)
 at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:189:in `rescue in exec'
 ...
caused by: command failed with error code 1: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 799, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 799, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 799, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 799, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 799, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)
Error occurred during build: Command 08_collectstatic failed (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
 at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/executor-1.0/lib/executor/exec.rb:81:in `sh'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/executor-1.0/lib/executor/exec.rb:24:in `sh'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/cfn-wrapper.rb:51:in `call_cfn_script'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/cfn-wrapper.rb:28:in `run_config_sets'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/infrahooks/infra-embeddedpostbuild.rb:20:in `execute!'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/executable.rb:56:in `instance_eval'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/executable.rb:56:in `execute!'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:213:in `block (3 levels) in exec_stage'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:169:in `call'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:169:in `exec'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:126:in `timeout_exec'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:110:in `block in create'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:109:in `instance_eval'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:109:in `create'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:209:in `block (2 levels) in exec_stage'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:207:in `each'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:207:in `each_with_index'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:207:in `block in exec_stage'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:169:in `call'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:169:in `exec'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:126:in `timeout_exec'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:110:in `block in create'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:109:in `instance_eval'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:109:in `create'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:204:in `exec_stage'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:158:in `execute!'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:68:in `run'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command-processor.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in execute!'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:169:in `call'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:169:in `exec'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:126:in `timeout_exec'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:110:in `block in create'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:109:in `instance_eval'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:109:in `create'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command-processor.rb:62:in `block in execute!'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command-processor.rb:106:in `execute_command'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command-processor.rb:60:in `execute!'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/bin/command-processor:46:in `<top (required)>'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/command-processor:23:in `load'
 from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/command-processor:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: did you try logging into the server and performing the action yourself?

Comment: That's how I've been proceeding, but it can be difficult to replicate the exact shell environment at various stages of the eb deploy. For instance, the Python AMI does some magic for installing `requirements.txt` between the `commands:` and `container_commands:` that I originally couldn't replicate with `pip install -r requirements/aws.txt` as a container command ... ultimately had to add a pre-deploy script to move `requirements/aws.txt` to the location `requirements.txt` so that whatever EB does works. I would probably prefer a more vanilla AMI versus the various Python/Ruby/Etc flavors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply pipe the output to a log file and tail it during deployment:

```
commands:
  01-install-git:
    command: "yum install -y git &>> /tmp/deploy.log"
  02-install-nodejs-npm:
    command: "yum install -y --enablerepo=epel nodejs npm &>> /tmp/deploy.log"
  03-install-grunt:
    command: "npm install -g grunt-cli &>> /tmp/deploy.log"
  04-install-coffee:
    command: "npm install -g coffee-script &>> /tmp/deploy.log"
  05-install-bower:
    command: "npm install -g bower &>> /tmp/deploy.log"
container_commands:
  01_grunt:
    command: "export PATH=$PATH; grunt prod &>> /tmp/deploy.log"
```